# PHP echo to text field... cut off at beginning

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

Right, strange one here... might just be me at 4am but here goes.
I have the following data inside a variable named "commandstring".
Basically just a bunch of CURLs. Its for work so I sanitized the data.

```
curl -k -X PUT http://system/user/summary/12345 -H \"Content-Type:application/xml\" -H \"userType:sometype\" -H \"userName:someuser\" -H \"userPasswordHash:somepasswordhashhere\" -H \"userId:12345\" -d \"<user-summary><userId>12345</userId><dob-status>somestatushere</dob-status><modified>30/09/2017 03:03:09.000</modified></user-summary>\"
curl -k -X POST "http://system/user/12345/message\" -H \"Content-Type:application/xml\" -H \"userType:sometype\" -H \"userName:someuser\" -H\"userPasswordhash:somepasswordhashhere\" -d \"<user-message><message-text>somemessage</message-text><status>Closed</status><legacy-category>Somelegacycategory</legacy-category></user-message>\"">
```

Now, obviously when I echo these straight onto a PHP page is thinks the tags in the CURLs are HTML and it looks really messed up, but most of the text is there. It just gets funny after each "-d", which is to be expected.

The user of this will be copying the text off the page to run manually for now.
It will eventually run the CURLs itself, but for now I need the CURLs to appear exact on the page.

I'm now trying to echo the CURLs into an HTML textarea, which shows all the tags as intended. The problem is it cuts off everything up the content for the first "-d"

This only happens on the first line... any subsequent lines, no matter how many, are not affected.

```
<userId>12345</userId><dob-status>somestatushere</dob-status><modified>30/09/2017 03:03:09.000</modified></user-summary>\"
curl -k -X POST \"http://system/user/12345/message\" -H \"Content-Type:application/xml\" -H \"userType:sometype\" -H \"userName:someuser\" -H\"userPasswordhash:somepasswordhashhere\" -d \"<user-message><message-text>somemessage</message-text><status>Closed</status><legacy-category>somelegacycategory</legacy-category></user-message>\"
```

You can see there where it starts at "userId" instead of the curl, but I'm not sure why its cutting off there.
As I said before, I KNOW the entire text is stored in the variable, because it's there from just an echo.

Not sure if it matters at this point, but I'm getting the string like so:

```
$commandstring=$_POST['hiddenstring'];
```

and then I'm echoing into the textarea like this (this is where I think the problem is)

```
<textarea id="commandstring" rows="200" cols="200" name="commandstring" value="<?php echo $commandstring; ?>"></textarea>
```

I'm assuming its something stupid I've overlooked but ifanyone can help I will be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use the `value` attribute, put it between the tags - `<textarea id="commandstring" rows="200" cols="200" name="commandstring"><?php echo $commandstring; ?></textarea>` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: Escape it and it should work fine, http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

Comment: @Sean that works perfectly, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just to mark as answered... followed Sean's example and moved:

```
<?php echo $commandstring; ?>
```

out of the "value" and now inbetween the textarea tags

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
 <textarea id="commandstring" rows="200" cols="200" name="commandstring">
 <?php echo $commandstring; ?>
 </textarea>
```